# Outputting form result

Tags: php

How do you output a form result on another page? Like if I make a drop-down list about gender. And I chose Female. How can I make the result be posted to my main page next to the "Gender:"?
Sorry, I'm still a beginner

Comment: *Too* ~ [`>>>>>........ ♫ here ♫ ........<<<<<`](http://myphpform.com/) ~ *Broad*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping things simple here...
You will need 2 files. A file with your form, and a file to handle your form.

form.php

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <select name="gender">
        <option value=""> Choose Gender </select>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    // grab other input values in the same way...

    // send email or whatever else
?>

<h1>Thank You</h1>
<p>You have said you are a <?php echo $gender; ?>.</p>
```

**Note** Make sure to sanitize any data! Using the super global $_POST directly isn't exactly best practice, but it will work for this example.

Comment: Thanks dragons! There are some minor mistakes you did but I got it now!